# How to skip welcome page after factory restore? I don't have access to Google

Tags: nexus-7, google-account, connection-issues, proxy

I'm from China and I can't access google without setting up a vpn/vps.

I recently got an update to 5.0.2 for my Nexus 7 2013 (WIFI) tablet. 
I got stuck at the Welcome page. I think I'm supposed to enter my Google account, but I don't have access to Google. There was a "skip" option in previous versions.

I'm now able to restore the tablet to previous versions of Android. Does anyone know which version doesn't require account at Welcome page? Is there any walk-around for this issue if I want to update to 5.0.2? I tried proxy for WIFI, it didn't work, though I think it's a promising way.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using a HTTPS (not HTTP) proxy located in the US. :)